# How can I wire three different lights together

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

making a sculpture and need to know the proper way to wire different lights into one string. is there an issue with stringing up an led, regular bulba and christmas light with different watts?

Comment: Can you provide any additional information about the bulbs? If you are intending to use bulbs from those sources but not necessarily in the original configuration, you may need to be concerned with the bulb voltages. many different "string lights: have bulbs in series because the individual bulbs are rated for a lower voltage than what you apply to them as a set.

Comment: It would appear you are not experienced with electrical circuits, since you are mixing three radically different kinds of light sources there.  Wattage is almost irrelevant; voltage matters.  I strongly recommend you find an electrician or a trusted friend who is knowledgeable to help you design your circuit.  Better than than risking serious injury or  possibly a fire.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you wire them in parallel (all hots connected together and all neutrals connected together) and each is rated for the voltage you're using, it should be fine. (I'm assuming that the wire is large enough diameter for the current being drawn, the wire insulation is rated for the voltage, you properly ground everything, and other safety issues.)

It's really no different than plugging a 25 watt bulb, a 50 watt bulb and a 100 watt bulb into the same power strip.

Edit: upon rereading your question, I am concerned and you writing about putting the lights in a "string". If you are talking about a serial string of low voltage lights connected to a higher voltage source (e. g. a string of 20 x 6 volt lights connected to 120 volt mains voltage), then no, you cannot mix wattages. You can probably mix different types of lights as long as the rated voltage and **actual** wattage (not equivalent wattage) are the same. If you have a "60-watt equivalent" LED which actually draws 10 watts, you must match that with other 10-watt lights. Also, you may have problems mixing LEDs and incandescent lights. Incandescent lights have a much smaller resistance when cold. If you have a bunch of incandescent lights and a few LEDs, when powered on cold, the LEDs may receive overvoltage and burn out.

Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I'm concerned you are making many assumptions about the items the OP intends to wire up.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I tried to cover everything I could think of, particularly that everything is rated for the appropriate voltage. I agree that the OP seems to be a novice but hopefully he will note all of the safety concerns.